# How to remove extra line break/empty cell Google Sheets importrange/query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, line-breaks, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Here is my formula (I have edited the name of my sheet as I cannot allow access to it).

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("my sheet","Prices"),"select Col1 where Col4 contains '"& L1 &"' limit 1",1)
```

This is working perfectly for all entries except 1 of them where it is importing 2 cells (the first one blank, the second with the desired result). Since the cell below is filled it cannot overwrite it, and I don't want it to. What would cause this phantom empty cell and how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: You can also try adding *AND Col1 IS NOT NULL* just before *limit 1*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the blank undesired cell is in the first column add `and Col1 is not null` like:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("my sheet", "Prices"), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col4 contains '"&L1&"'
    and Col1 is not null
  limit 1", 1)
```

---

if you have actual line break issue use regex with `\n` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("my sheet", "Prices"), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col4 contains '"&L1&"'
  limit 1", 1), "\n", ))
```

Comment: Adding the not null worked - can you explain why that would have been necessary to fix this? And thank you so much for your help!

Comment: well, the `and Col1 is not null` literally translates as "if cells in the first column are not empty" - so basically that's what you want - to skip empty rows